# error exception access violation in JNotify

Tags: java

I am trying to implement JNotify. but I am getting a bit weird error messages when I compiled the program. I get the sample code from this site ttp://jnotify.sourceforge.net/sample.html

as an info, JNotify is used for directory monitoring and this is how my source code looks like.

this is the content of the class watching.java

```
import net.contentobjects.jnotify.JNotifyListener;
import net.contentobjects.jnotify.JNotify;


public class watching{

public void watching(String s) throws Exception {
    // path to watch
    String path = System.getProperty(s);

    // watch mask, specify events you care about,
    // or JNotify.FILE_ANY for all events.
    int mask = JNotify.FILE_CREATED  | 
               JNotify.FILE_DELETED  | 
               JNotify.FILE_MODIFIED | 
               JNotify.FILE_RENAMED;

    // watch subtree?
    boolean watchSubtree = true;

    // add actual watch
    int watchID = JNotify.addWatch(path, mask, watchSubtree, new Listener());

    // sleep a little, the application will exit if you
    // don't (watching is asynchronous), depending on your
    // application, this may not be required
    Thread.sleep(1000000);

    // to remove watch the watch
    boolean res = JNotify.removeWatch(watchID);
    if (!res) {
      // invalid watch ID specified.
    }
  }
  class Listener implements JNotifyListener {
    public void fileRenamed(int wd, String rootPath, String oldName,
        String newName) {
      print("renamed " + rootPath + " : " + oldName + " -> " + newName);
    }
    public void fileModified(int wd, String rootPath, String name) {
      print("modified " + rootPath + " : " + name);
    }
    public void fileDeleted(int wd, String rootPath, String name) {
      print("deleted " + rootPath + " : " + name);
    }
    public void fileCreated(int wd, String rootPath, String name) {
      print("created " + rootPath + " : " + name);
    }
    void print(String msg) {
      System.err.println(msg);
    }
  }
}
```

then this is the main class that named nowwatch.java

```
public class nowwatch
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
        watching hello = new watching();
        hello.watching("C:/Users/Raden/Documents/Downloads");
    }
}
```

but why did the error went like this? I had screenshot the error so that you can see it by clicking on this [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bJXo.jpg)

has any of you ever experience this type of error? any help would be appreciated though. 
thanks

Comment: For code samples, use the code button (10101010) or indent everything at least 4 spaces.  I fixed it for you.

Comment: first time user here.thanks for the correction. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JNotify surely uses JNI to interface with the OS-dependent notification APIs.  Looks like there's a bug in JNotify.  Have you tried asking on the JNotify forum on SourceForge?

Comment: no, not yet though.there is just a few tutorials about JNotify and I can't find any information about this error messages in google.can you tell me of another way to do directory monitoring other than JNotify? I really need this kind of functionality

Comment: There's a commercial library JxFileWatcher (http://www.teamdev.com/jxfilewatcher).  If you really need this and can't get JNotify to work you might consider it (I have no connection with the authors).  Also do a google search on "java filesystem monitor"

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problems. Because we used [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna) anyways, we just used the FileMonitor example from this framework. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

it ask for jNotify.dll file, make sure that you have placed that file to the window or in jre/bin or jdk/bin. and then try it will start working.