# Substitute for JNotify?

Tags: java, jnotify

I have used JNotify on the windows. But I am getting weird exception.

An unexpected error has been detected by Java Runtime Environment:

EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x6d94200c, pid=22944, tid=20528

Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (1.6.0_01-b06 mixed mode, sharing)
 Problematic frame:
 V  [jvm.dll+0xd200c]

So I wanted to know some subsitute of the JNotify.
API which looks change in file system and works fine windows and linux.

Comment: Same happened before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840844/error-exception-access-violation-in-jnotify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had the same problems. Because we used [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna) anyways, we just used the FileMonitor example from this framework. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

Java7 will have/has some solutions for this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html